# How can I count a value in a list with str index in python?

Tags: python, count

how can I count '2' in this dict?

```
{'count': 2, 0: '1', 1: '2'}
```

Is there any built-in function?

Comment: I don't know if it matters to your question, but that's a dictionary, not a list.  Generally for counting stuff you would use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), but your question doesn't really make it clear what it is you're trying to count

Comment: This question is very hard to understand as written. Please refer to our [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for help writing questions

Answer (score 0):

First, it is a `dict`, not a `list`. You can use `sum` with a generator:

```
d = {'count': 2, 0: '1', 1: '2'}
s = sum(v == 2 for v in d.values())
```

If you want to catch both `2` (the integer) and `'2'` (the string):

```
s = sum(v in ('2', 2) for v in d.values())
```